# Cybersource transactions fail with Misconfigured paymentech processor error

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource

Cybersource Transactions are failing with the following errors on Test environment. Tried creating new merchant profile as well as by cloning existing working profile with no luck. Any help in how to fix the issue will be of great help.

```
Client App : Secure Acceptance Web/Mobile
Reason Code : 102
Reply Message : Misconfigured paymentech processor
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the full request and response I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing you are sending a currency that has not been configured. Only CyberSource support can setup your configuration. Here are your options to contact support - https://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=C529

If you are an unsigned CyberSource customer you can contact your sales rep to assist with setting that up.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Any currency other than USD requires Cybersource support to setup on your test account, otherwise it fails to process.

Answer (score 2):

Chase Paymentech Solutions test simulator defaults to USD currency for test 
transactions.

Comment: Can you better explain why this matters here?

Comment: Dear, for a testing purpose USD be a default currency.If you want to test in any other Currency you may contact to support team in order to add their respective currency